# can someone tell something about expression(this.scrollHeight > 27 ? "30px" : "auto"); in css?

Tags: css

```
.newEventItem .eventDateInfo .eventVenue
{
    display: block;
    color: #CCC;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: expression(this.scrollHeight > 27 ? "30px" : "auto");//is css support this?
    max-height: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually IE's Dynamic Property.

> It allows you to set a CSS property
>   not to a constant, but to the result
>   of a JavaScript expression

You can read more in this msdn article

[About Dynamic Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> As of Windows Internet Explorer 8,
>   dynamic properties have been
>   deprecated and are only supported for
>   Web pages displayed in IE5 mode or IE7
>   mode.

Also read this one

[Ending Expressions](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/10/16/ending-expressions.aspx)

> Design criteria such as standard
>   compliance, performance, reliability
>   and security framed the design of IE8
>   as whole, for new as well as existing
>   features. As a result, CSS expressions
>   are no longer supported in IE8
>   standards mode.

Answer (score 2):

This is not something supported by CSS. It is a propriety Microsoftism.

It means "If this.scrollHeight is more than 27, set this property to 30px otherwise set it to auto". I think it is an attempt to simulate max-height in IE6.

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed as Quentin mentioned, this is an attempt emulate "max-height" which is not supported in IE6 and IE7, the EXPRESSION is just Javascript code that get evaluated constantly in the page, so that's why the 27 is less than 30, because if you do

```
 "this.scrollHeight > 30 ? "30px""
```

the expression enters in a loop...well it's always in a loop, but the value always repeats itself...

anyway, just refrasing what Quentin said, the expression checks if the object is larger than 27px, so if it is, you activate the overflow property cause now it is bigger, and that's how you emulate "max-height"

you could do it other ways like:

```
<div id="div_id" 
     style="height: expression( 
                                if(document.getElementById('div_id').offsetHeight>27px){ 
                                 document.getElementById('div_id').style.height = '30px'
                                }
                              //use offsetHeight if the original loaded content already occupies space...if not,instead of ".offsetHeight", you can use "style.height" if height is defined...

                              );" >
  content--lbalbalbalbalblablablalb
</div>
```

anyway..the problem with expressions seems to be that it gets evaluated constantly...so...watch for that...anyway, a source for min/max width/height:

http://perishablepress.com/press/2007/01/16/maximum-and-minimum-height-and-width-in-internet-explorer/

and something I'm struggling..trying to only do a one-time expression:
http://vacskamati.blogspot.com/2008/10/one-time-execution-of-ie-css.html

and a yahoo article that explains a little more of what I said =P
http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_6/